# Can I highlight the prompt line in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, console, rails-console

Working more in the Rails console these days and it would be really helpful if I could somehow highlight (color, **bold**, anything) the lines where I'm typing a command so they stand out from all the rails output.

Could even be just highlighting the prompt somehow. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize your prompt in the Rails console, then you are probably looking for the [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry/) gem that lets you customize the prompt, including adding colors:

https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Customization-and-configuration#Config_prompt

To use it automatically with Rails, include the [`pry-rails`](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) gem as well.

If you want syntax highlighting as you type in the pry console then you'll also want the [`pry-coolline`](https://github.com/pry/pry-coolline) gem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the [awesome print gem](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print)?